# Service Endpoint naming convention

Tags: wcf, naming-conventions

Are there any best practices to follow while designing Service endpoint URI considering that the service would have multiple endpoints (SOAP1.1, REST) and over a period of time have multiple versions available ?

I am considering something similar to :

```
http://<domain>.com/<API Name>/<Service Name>/<Vx>/<EndpointType like SOAP11 or REST>
```

eg.,
http://example.com/ExampleAPI/ExampleSearch/V2/REST
http://example.com/ExampleAPI/ExampleSearch/V2/SOAP11

Any thoughts ?